# how to remove case sensitivitiy in jquery search filter

Tags: jquery

i found this fiddle.., it works fine but can anyone know how to remove the case sensitivity in  it.? thank you newbie here, any help is appreciated ^^

http://jsfiddle.net/ukW2C/3/

```
$("#searchInput").keyup(function () {
//split the current value of searchInput
var data = this.value.split(" ");
//create a jquery object of the rows
var jo = $("#fbody").find("tr");
if (this.value == "") {
    jo.show();
    return;
}
//hide all the rows
jo.hide();

//Recusively filter the jquery object to get results.
jo.filter(function (i, v) {
    var $t = $(this);
    for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
        if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})
//show the rows that match.
.show();
}).focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
   $(this).css({
    "color": "black"
});
$(this).unbind('focus');
}).css({
"color": "#C0C0C0"
```

});

Comment: And were is the fiddle?

Comment: Where is the Fiddle link?

Comment: nice fiddle - but where?

Comment: sorry just sir., just a new one here., just reviewed how to share links ^^

Comment: either convert sting to lower or uppercase while matching both strings :)

Comment: thank you for your help.., ^^ got it finally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)

```
jo.filter(function (i, v) {
    var $t = $(this);
    for (var d = 0; d < data.length; ++d) {
        console.log( (data[d]).toLowerCase() );
        if ($t.is(":contains('" + data[d].toLowerCase() + "')")) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
})
```